# Unable to connect object with outlet in Xcode with automatic like below

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I am facing problem to connect an object with outlet so when i open assistant editor there are no related file found on automatic...why `NSObject` file showing always.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right where Automatic is highlighted, to the left of that there is an arrow, clicking that solved my issue

[image]

Comment: I think you're the one that needs to look more carefully.

Comment: There are plenty of rude people out there, try something new @trojanfoe

Comment: I am not being rude.

Comment: This solved my problem, mind if that might solve his as well? @trojanfoe

Comment: hey @trojanfoe, when i click on this arrow as u suggest me then my source file open but the main issue is drag and drop the object outlet not perform...this is my problem

Comment: @arun Are you sure you wanted to direct that statement to me or the person who wrote this answer?

Comment: @arun Click on your Xib file and Go to Identity inspector and make sure that you connect your .xib with proper class.

Comment: And you pointed in your question that the main issue was that you couldnt see related files.. I think now you can view source files.. But you cant drag from Xib to source file because you may not have set appropriate class in xib's identity inspector

Comment: @AkshanshThakur sir thanks a lot...this solved my problem..actually i'm new..in my project there is one main class and it have many subclasses so i  was connecting main class reference to subclass identity inspector which was wrong...thank u very much sir

Comment: No problem! Glad to help
@arun Would be great if you choose the answer :) and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Because the storyboard don't have equivalent for automatic.

You have to select manual and navigate to the desired source file

Comment: Hey @David, that guy not using storyboard. he is using Xib

Comment: hey @David, when i select manual and choose my source file then the main problem is drag and drop the object outlet not perform...so please tell me solution